# Positive pdf must be continuous?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose $f(x) > 0 $ is a pdf that is strictly positive on the entire real line.  Must $f$ be continuous?

I've thought about trying to say that the corresponding cdf must be positive on any interval and trying to use that, but I'm not even sure if that is true.

Can someone provide me with any insight?

Comment: Answer this question by going to the definition of continuity of a function: is the inverse image of an open set open for $f$? That piece of information, just being strictly positive, wouldn't work if $f$ was some random function. Consider a binomial distribution.

Comment: Given an absolutely continuous random variable $X$, a density is any function $f$ which satisfies $$\mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\ \mathsf dt.$$ This tells us nothing about the actual values that $f$ takes at any given point, let alone properties such as continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. Consider $f(x)=\frac 1  4$ for $|x| \leq 1$ and $f(x)=\frac {3/4} {x^{4}}$ for $|x| \geq 1$.

Comment: What happens at $x=0$?

Comment: @Henry I have simplified my example.